# How to set a global object which is define in a class

Tags: python, object, pyqt, global

**I would like to set a global object "view" and it has a class method
How can I acheive it.**

I use

```
V = View(self)
V = View(QGraphicsView)
V = View()
```

all is fail

when I use the third type , compiler message :

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'
```

the following is my class want to call:

```
class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setSceneRect(QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if can_draw == 1 :
            self._start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if can_draw == 1:
            start = QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
            end = QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self.scene().addItem(
                QGraphicsLineItem(QLineF(start, end)))
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing `def __init__(self, parent):`, you force your view to have a parent.

A Qt widget doesn't have to have a parent (It will be automatically set when you add the widget in another using `setParent()`, a layout, etc.).

You can add a default value to the *parent* paramater by writing `def __init__(self, parent=None):`.
Then, use `V = View()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include an argument in `__init__` without including it when you instantiate the class.

You would have to:

```py
class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setSceneRect(QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if can_draw == 1 :
            self._start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if can_draw == 1:
            start = QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
            end = QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self.scene().addItem(
                QGraphicsLineItem(QLineF(start, end)))
```

Then you would instantiate it by

```py
v = View()
```

And then you have access to it's methods

Comment: Have you tested the code you are showing? IMHO I think it will throw an exception that pointed out that parent is not defined